# Why am I getting errors using virtuals?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Im trying to create some polymorphic classes using a couple of examples I have, I followed them to the best I could and had to kinda work around it, not quite sure why this isn't compiling.

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<memory>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

class Vehicle {
public:
    string colour;
    int wheels;
    //deconstructor
    virtual ~Vehicle(){}
    virtual void setColour(string col) {}
    virtual string getColour() { return colour; }
    virtual int getWheels() { return wheels; }
    virtual void setWheels(int numWheels){};
    Vehicle(int numWheels, string col) : wheels(numWheels), colour(col){}
};

class Auto : public Vehicle{
public:
    Auto(int numWheels, string col) : Vehicle(numWheels, col){}
    void setWheels(int numWheels){ wheels = numWheels; }
    void setColour(string col){ colour = col; }
    int getWheels();
    string getColour();
};

class Bike : public Vehicle{
private:
    string sCol;
    int iWheel;
public:
    Bike(int numWheels, string col) : Vehicle(numWheels, col){}
    void setWheels(int numWheels){ wheels = numWheels; }
    void setColour(string col){ colour = col; }
    int getWheels();
    string getColour();
};


int main(){
    Auto car1(4, "white");
    cout << car1.getColour() << endl;
    Bike bike1(2, "grey");
    cout << bike1.getColour() << endl;
}
```

Im getting a weird Error, I have a final exam coming up in about 12 hours, and I don't get why this C++ code won't compile.

Comment: You are receiving *linker* not *compiler* errors. `getColour` needs a definition.

Comment: im a little confused here, where does it need the definition.

THANKS  I figured it out after re looking at what was going on since it need a definition :D

Comment: Where is the body code for the `Auto` and `Bike` classes?  You declared them with some non-inline declarations for some methods, so their actual implementations exist somewhere else, but where? That is what the linker is complaining about.  It can't find them.

Comment: What is the error?  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  How does this show polymorphism in main()?